# Modal flickering with KeyboardAvoidingView

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile

On android the keyboard causes my modal to move up to avoid the keyboard.
I would like to change that behavior so I used `KeyboardAvoidingView` with `enabled` set to false.
It works but it causes my modal to glitch and "flicker" when the keyboard opens, and it is really ugly. Has anyone encountered this glitch before ?

this is my code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Modal, Platform, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';

var padding;

if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  padding = 40;
} else {
  padding = 30;
}

function CustomModal({ children, show, style }) {
  return (

    <Modal visible={show} transparent>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.screen} behavior={Platform.OS == "ios" ? "padding" : "height"} keyboardVerticalOffset={100} enabled={false}>
      <View style={styles.outerView}>
        <View style={{ ...styles.innerView, ...style }}>
          {children}
        </View>
      </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </Modal>

  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  outerView: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#00000080',

  },
  innerView: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    padding: padding,
    marginHorizontal: 30,
    borderRadius: 200,

  }
});


export default CustomModal;
```